# Asus TUF GAMING FX506 No Detect Wifi Controller Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Live USB

Tags: wireless, asus

I have an Asus FX506 TUF GAMING i7 notebook. I am testing ubuntu 20 from live usb (or boot from usb) with kernel 5.11 with live usb and it does not recognize the wifi drivers/controllers, will the wifi work if I install it on the hard disk?
[no detected wifi adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKmsx.png)

I have tried with ubuntu 21.10 no-lts (also live usb), kernel 5.13 and it works without problems

someone who can help me according to your experience please?

I want to avoid installing external drivers and updating kernel

Greetings
Matias

Comment: Looks like the 5.13 kernel is available in Ubuntu 20.04's standard repos, so you have a choice of installing it, or of using 21.10 (with a subsequent upgrade to the 22.04 long term support version when released).

Comment: Hello, I have tried, but I got an error when installing install it (in a virtual machine). According to this page: https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html, the 3 Wi-Fi-6 drivers that is my case need a kernel as much larger than 5.10, and ubuntu 20.04 is kernel 5.11.

As I am doing the tests on a live usb, I cannot restart the notebook because I lose everything I have done.

Comment: The 5.10+ in your link means kernel 5.10 or later, so 5.11 should be OK. The latest  5.13 kernel I see in the standard 20.04 repos is linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-1017-oem (or the linux-image-5.13.0-1017-oem version).